# How to Associate an Object with a DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a master object in my JS setup, i.e.:

```
var myGarage = {
    cars: [
        {
            make: "Ford",
            model: "Escape",
            color: "Green",
            inuse: false
        },
        {
            make: "Dodge",
            model: "Viper"
            color: "Red",
            inuse: true
        },
        {
            make: "Toyota",
            model: "Camry"
            color: "Blue",
            inuse: false
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I loop over my cars and put them in a table.  In the table I also have a button that lets me toggle the car as "in use" and "not in use".

How can I associate the DOM Element of every row with its corresponding car, so that if I toggle the "inuse" flag, I can update the master object?

Comment: Did you consider jQuery's `.data()` method?

Comment: I did, but how do I store a reference to each car object inside?

Comment: Something like `$("<tr ...>").data(car).appendTo(table)`

Comment: I know this is not related to answering your question, but you should consider designing your application using one of the MVVM,MVC,etc design pattern supported frameworks such as KnockoutJS or AngularJS. It will certainly help simplify your UI binding logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest considering `addEventListener`, and a constructor that conforms your objects to the `eventListener` interface.

That way you can have a nice association between your object, your element, and its handlers.

To do this, make a constructor that's specific to your data.

```
function Car(props) {
    this.make = props.make;
    this.model = props.model;
   // and so on...

    this.element = document.createElement("div"); // or whatever

    document.body.appendChild(this.element);      // or whatever

    this.element.addEventListener("click", this, false);
}
```

Then implement the interface:

```
Car.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "click": this.click(e);
        // add other event types if needed
    }
}
```

Then implement your `.click()` handler on the prototype.

```
Car.prototype.click = function(e) {
    // do something with this.element...
    this.element.style.color = "#F00";

    // ...and the other properties
    this.inuse = !this.inuse
}
```

So then you can just loop over the Array, and make a new `Car` object for each item, and it'll create the new element and add the listener(s).

```
myGarage.cars.forEach(function(obj) {
    new Car(obj)
})
```

Comment: he said he's using jQuery, so each of those can be abbreviated to one-liners.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.  I am actually doing it very similar to this.  The above description was just a shorter explanation to set up my actual problem:  How do I store a reference to each car object (within the myGarage object) inside the `tr` rowElement, so that I can easily update the original object inside a click handler.

Comment: @Barmar: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see where it says "using jQuery". I see the tag, but that's it.

Comment: That's what I was referring to. If he tags it jquery, it seems appropriate to give a jquery answer.

Comment: @Steve: It's the other way around. Store the `tr` in the object, but then pass the object to `addEventListener`. That way the listeners on your prototype have access to both the object and the element.

Comment: @Barmar: I see your point, except that this is specific behavior not available in jQuery *(though you can sort of do it with event data)*, so I thought it was worth describing.

Comment: I am OK with vanilla JS... I just tagged it with jQuery in case it offers a better way to store the reference.

Comment: @amnotiam - oh, that is interesting... I haven't thought about storing the DOM Element inside the object.  Let me try this.

Comment: @Steve: The magic is in the `.handleEvent()` method. Having this method in your object's prototype chain triggers a different behavior of `addEventListener` where the `.handleEvent()` method automatically becomes the handler, and `this` in the method becomes your object. You can do this without a constructor, but the constructor ties it all together nicely.

Comment: @Steve: You can actually eliminate the `this.element` since the element will be available on the `e` event object as `e.currentTarget`. Either way works.

Answer (score 20):

You can actually attach an object directly to a node:

```
var n = document.getElementById('green-ford-escape');
n.carObject = myGarage.cars[0];
n.onclick = function() {
  doSomethingWith(this.carObject);
}
```

For the same of removing ambiguity, in some cases, it's more clear write the above event handler to refer to `n` instead of `this`:

```
n.onclick = function() {
  doSomethingWith(n.carObject);
}
```

You can also refer directly to the object from the attached event:

```
var n = document.getElementById('green-ford-escape');
n.onclick = function() {
    doSomethingWith(myGarage.cars[0]);
}
```

In the latter case, `myGarage` does *not* have to be global. You can do this and expect it to work correctly:

```
(function(){

    var myGarage = { /* ... etc ... */ };

    var n = document.getElementById('green-ford-escape');
    n.onclick = function() {
        doSomethingWith(myGarage.cars[0]);
    }

})();
```

The node's event function will "hold onto" the local variable correctly, effectively creating a private variable.

You can test this in your Chrome/FF/IE console:

```
var o = {a: 1};
var n = document.createElement('div');
n.innerHTML = "click me";
n.data = o;
n.onclick = function() { n.data.a++; console.log(n.data, o); }
document.body.appendChild(n);
```

You should see the console log two identical objects with each click, each with incrementing `a` values.

**Beware** that setting `n.data` to a primitive will not create a reference. It'll copy the value.

Comment: Sweet... this is what I was looking for.  So it is totally OK to store a reference to the nested object attached to the DOMElement?

Comment: @Steve I haven't checked the specs lately. And I suspect referring to the object in the event handler is less "dangerous" in some folks' minds. But, attaching the object directly to the node *will work*. Just watch for collisions with builtin attributes -- I think the spec suggests prefixing all custom attributes with `x-vendorname-` or `data-`. (`x-vendor` might be the recommendation for user agents.)

Comment: Be aware that extending DOM objects this way is safe-ish only in controlled environments. Here’s a great article by kangax: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/#lack_of_specification .

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 data-* attribute to find out which row it is. You must be doing something like this

```
var table = $('<table>'); // Let's create a new table even if we have an empty table in our DOM. Simple reason: we will achieve single DOM operation (Faster)

for (var i=0; i<myGarbage.cars.length; i++) {
    // Create a new row and append to table
    var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table);

    var carObject = myGarbage.cars[i];
    // Traverse the JSON object for each car
    for (var key in carObject) {
        // Create other cells. I am doing the last one
        var td = $('<td>').appendTo(tr);
        var button = $('<button>').attr('data-carId', i).addClass('toggle-inuse').appendTo(td);
    }
}
// If en ampty table awaits me in DOM
$('#tableId').html(table.html());
```

Now we will add event listener on button :-

```
$('.toggle-inuse').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).data('carId');
    myGarbage.cars[i].inuse = !myGarbage.cars[i].inuse; //Wow done
}
```

Try this out !!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want some sort of ID or distinct row in your information, else you'll have to rely on the array index to do this.  Either way you'll want to store the data using [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

So when you loop through:

```
for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
  var div = '<tr data-car="' + JSON.stringify(array[i]) + '" data-index="' + i + '"><td></td></tr>'
}
```

And on your click event:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var carIndex = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-index');
    var carData = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-car');
    if (carData) carData = JSON.parse(carData);

    myGarage.cars[carIndex].inUse = true;
})
```

If you bind the data to the DOM, you may not even need to update the actual JS data.  Could go over each row in the table and re-create the data-object you created the table from.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I store a copy of each car's object in the `data-attribute`.  That's not what I want. I want a reference to the original object in the master object.

Comment: So only store the index using data-attributes?  There's no sure-fire way of getting a reference to a DOM element. If you were to find it with jQuery and save it to your car's object, the jQuery reference will not stay set reliably.  You might be able to store the raw table element (document.getElementById for example) to your main myGarage object, however you'll need to test the reference stays between function calls.

Comment: Why we are adding carIndex to row..Why not add it on the button itself. It will save me one DOM query to find the nearest row. My answer does the same. Let me know if there is a reason for it.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica: If there's a 1 to 1 relationship between cars and rows, you can eliminate the `data-index` because a table row maintains its own index via its `.rowIndex` property.

Comment: Hypothetically you'll have more than one action per car.  (In my experience) it's best to bind data on the top-most element that the data represents.  That way when you need to get several pieces of data off that element (getting several input's values for example) you can get it off the highest element (which you'll have as a variable to in these situations).

Comment: @am not i am I generally don't feel comfortable assuming the location of the elements will not change.  Invariably you'll want to re-order them later and have to rethink this problem.  This is why I said I would use some sort of unique ID on the myGarage.cars data rather than just an array index.