# Syncing object with HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a website with a table. I'm loading in data to the table from objects. The cells of the table have `contenteditable` enabled.

I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery, nothing more.

Table

```
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="date">Date</th>
            <th class="start">Start</th>
            <th class="end">End</th>
            <th class="title">Title</th>
            <th class="rem">Remarks</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableBody">

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Code to fill table:

```
$("#tableBody").append("<tr>" + date + start + end + descr + rem "<td contenteditable='true'></td></tr>");
```

This is the object I'm trying to sync:

```
function Shift(start, end, descr) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.descr = descr;
}
```

date start and end etc are preformatted to be TD's.

How do I achieve that people can change the text in the table and have it update the object as well?

Comment: provide relevant code

Comment: My first guess would be to use a library like knockout - but it is hard to know what you are after without code.

Comment: @Wolff - true, it is tough to know what he is looking for.

Comment: Sorry, thought I was asking a pretty generic question. How to link a table to an object, but I've provided the code.

Comment: You need to specify what technologies / stack you are using, MVC, PHP, Knockout, C#, etc etc... so we can provide an answer in context of your question.  It's a little open ended.

Comment: Done, added text and updated tags.

Comment: So the data you are editing / storing is all in memory, you won't be saving it in a database etc?

Comment: We still don't know which object you are talking about

Comment: Nope, I'm processing the changes to the object and uploading the Shift to Google Calendar through their API.

Comment: Ok, if you are processing changes, you need to get the data first... how are you doing this?

Comment: The original in the object that I'm using to fill the table? That comes from a PDF that I'm reading and parsing. That bit is fine, I just want to give my users the opportunity to fine tune the descriptions.

Comment: well, provide the code that you use to create that initial object from the pdf... it then brings everything into context.

Comment: That's short of 3 pages of code, and I don't really think it's relevant to the question. As I said, in basis it's quite generic, how to link a HTML table and Javascript Object together. The initial object is static and won't change unless the table is changed.

Comment: Ok, then as the answer states below I would use a framework like Knockout.  That's probably the simplest solution.

Comment: @Difusio I've added my own answer which contains useful tutorials to go through, it should be easy to figure out what to do - if not reply to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this without a framework. Here's how:

Create the table as described above. Then instead of using contentEditable (which is poorly supported) fill every `<TD>` you'd wish to make editable with a `<textarea>`. Then give the textarea's name attribute the value of your column and give it the id that corresponds with the object you used to fill that particular row.

Then when any textarea is updated just update the corresponding object.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to "glue" data and view together. You could use a framework which supports data-binding like AngularJS, EmberJS, Knockout or Backbone. If you want to persist your data, you have to provide some kind of storage backend (mysql, sqlite,...)

Comment: I don't need persistence, once the object have been updated they will be processed and that's it. 

The thing is, I only have one table in my entire website that I want to apply this to, seems a bit heavy to introduce Angular or something else just for this one page right?

Comment: I was hoping for pointers to a custom solution, I have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113070/how-to-associate-an-object-with-a-dom-element but I'm not really sure if that's what I'm looking for. I wouldn't know how to convert that to a table.

Comment: Maybe you could use jQuery's [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function to observe if the content has changed and then fire a callback to update the object.

Comment: Sadly, this won't work: "The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. "

Answer (score 0):

I would use Knockout as the quickest solution.

This tutorial should get you started:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html

Comment: Checking it out as we speak. Thank you.

Comment: Another quick question - I'm guessing you are only ever going to have one row in the table?  Or will there be multiple pdf's read and multiple rows in the table?

Comment: Multiple rows, somewhere between 20 and 40.

Comment: If you need further help later I will try and find time to provide you with a jsfiddle.

Comment: How are you getting on? @Difusio

Comment: I'm still trying to get a workaround going without the frameworks. I'll let you know how it tends.