# Event delegate - Retrieve instance of class that a DOM element is a property of

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, scoping

I'm learning the ways of scoping and inheritance and am having a little difficulty retrieving the instance of a class of which a DOM element is a property. There is a Parent and lets say there can be unlimited Child(ren). Is there any way of getting the instance via an event delegate? Hopefully the following will help explain:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.element = document.createElement('div');
        this.element.setAttribute('class', 'parent');

        // add elements from instances
        this.element.appendChild(new Child(1, this).element);
        this.element.appendChild(new Child(2, this).element);
        this.element.appendChild(new Child(3, this).element);

        // event delegate
        this.element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            // would like to get the particular instance of the class "Child" that was clicked
        });
    }

    something(id) {
        console.log('something', id);
    }
}

class Child  {
    constructor(id, parentReference) {
        this.id = id;
        this.element = document.createElement('div');
        this.element.setAttribute('class', 'child');

        // would like to avoid adding a click event for each and use the parent as delegate
        this.element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            parentReference.something(this.id)
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense, welcome any and all feedback.

Also on another note, since I'm not storing the instances anywhere, only creating and appending an element to the DOM, will the Child instance remain intact as long as the DOM element remains rendered and other properties get used then be garbage collected? Should they be stored elsewhere, like an array to be safe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you're trying to do is actually Web Components : you could just make your class extend HTMLElement and benefit from the whole lifecycle which comes natively with [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

For example, you could have a `Parent` component which holds some `Child` components. As `Parent` and `Child` classes would be real HTMLElements, if you register a click event listener in the `Parent` object, you will receive click events triggered on the childs. And the clicked child instance will be available in the target property of the click event.

```
class ParentElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.classList.add('parent');

        // add elements from instances
        this.innerHTML = `
            <child-element data-sequence="1"></Child>
            <child-element data-sequence="2"></Child>
            <child-element data-sequence="3"></Child>
        `;

        // event delegate
        this.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            // Child instance is available in the event itself
            const child = e.target;
            this.something(child.id);
        });
    }

    something(id) {
        console.log('something', id);
    }
}
window.customElements.define('parent-element', Parent);

class ChildElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.id = this.dataset.sequence;
        this.classList.add('child');
    }
}
window.customElements.define('child-element', ChildElement);
```

Then you can just append the parent element into the dom :

```
document.body.appendChild(new ParentElement());
```

(Be careful, i didn't tested the previous example, this is just to give you an idea)

But maybe i get it wrong. In this case, i would suggest to avoid keeping a reference to a dom element into custom objects as it would probably be easy to get memory leaks (if you re render some portion of your page but keep references to `Parent` or `Child` instances then you'll also keep a reference to the corresponding dom node). Couldn't you go the other way around by attaching your custom objects onto dom nodes (a bit like a controller ?)

Hope this help,

Comment: Thanks for the great response @Sam I had not heard of Web Components and extending elements like this before, I will have to play with this in future, however for now it's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Your last sentence is exactly what I'm trying to do, just I figured there must be a "nicer" way to go about it. Just to be clear, you mean something like `element.customObj`, or along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113070/how-to-associate-an-object-with-a-dom-element)?

Comment: Only this answer provides almost the same issue I'm trying to avoid, eventListeners registered to each item and not delegated. I was just hoping to find a more elegant solution. Next, onto the memory leak possibility, that's very real. Going to have to think about this. Thanks again @Sam for the response, you've really got me thinking. So much for sleeping tonight :)

Comment: I added an example with custom elements, just in case. About custom objects, i was just refering to your `Parent` and `Child` class. Hope you find a solution that suits your need ;)

Comment: Thanks @Sam that's a great example and I'd probably go that route if browser support permitted and polyfill use was possible for this case (I should have mentioned that earlier). I ended up (similarly to above) using an index dataset attribute on the DOM element that matches the `Child` position in an array in the `Parent`. So there's a little more logic in the delegate but there's also now references to facilitate removal of potential memory leak items. Great answer Sam, thanks again for all the help and your time :+1: